# Select2 dropdown list not updating/highlighting correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

When I type anything into the search field, it always just shows the initial list (see screenshot).

[image]

I have a dropdownlist:

```
<asp:Dropdownlist ID="animals" name="animals" runat="server" />
```

It's being populated like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#animals").select2({
        placeholder: '-- None Selected --',
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: function () {return "json/animals.aspx";},
            dataType: "JSON",
            processResults:function(data){return {results: data};},
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax correctly gets the list like in the screenshot, but when I type in '1', it doesn't match it at all, just shows the whole list.  If I spam any key, then it errors out and gives an undefined in `jqXHR.responseText`.  Am I doing anything wrong here?  Here are my includes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 jQuery.getJSON('json/animals.aspx')
    .done( function( data ) {

            data = $.map(data, function(item) {
               // replace item. id and text with your animal json properties. 
                return { id: item.id, text: item.name}; 
            });

            jQuery('#animals').select2({
                placeholder: 'Type any ....',
                allowClear: true,
                minimumInputLength: 0,
                multiple: true,
                data: data
            });
        }
    );
```